# Presorted database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database to hold scientific data.  Each datum has a unique timestamp (in epoch time) and 8 doubles.  I plan on keeping each experiment in its own table, which may get anywhere from 100,000-10,000,000 rows.  I also for see the vast majority of DB reads to be from a single table at a time, requesting either every row in order of timestamp or some contiguous chunk of rows, again in chronological order by time stamp.  I know that in the most abstract sense db data is unordered, but is there a way to give a hint to the database that most if not all queries will sort on a specific column, allowing the DB to keep everything in order by that column and speed up reads?

Incase it matters I'm using MySQL:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386) using readline 5.1
```

I'm also open to a DB different structure if that helps.

Comment: Add a (B-tree) index on that column, then `ORDER BY` will be very fast.

Comment: For more explenation check http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/preordering-the-table-by-a-specified-column

Comment: Also worth a read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each timestamp is guarnateed to be different, then you could set that as a primary key, otherwise just create an index.